# Replaced thermopile, pilot light works, fireplace still won’t light

Tags: gas, fireplace, pilot-light, thermocouple

I have an Empire VFSR-18 fireplace. The pilot light wouldn’t stay on so I replaced the thermopile and the thermocouple assembly. The pilot light stays on and my voltmeter is giving me 0.47V (470mV).

I removed the switch and jumped the prongs and the fireplace still won’t light.

I also blew some compressed air down the gas lines to no avail.

Is the whole thing dead or is there something else I can try?

[image]

Comment: I read somewhere you need >700 mV signal

Comment: Knowing the specs for this particular fire place insert would be most useful. 470mV might work, or you might need 700+mV as noted above.

Comment: Turns out I’m an idiot and had one of the thermopile connectors installed in the wrong spot . Moved it and we are now up and running.

Comment: KD1980, you can self-answer this question since you have the answer. Be sure to Accept that answer so this question shows as Answered and not Open. Glad you got it figured out!